# J! not responding when selecting banner image

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm experiencing a weird problem:

When creating a new article I click the image button a popup window appears but it doesn't show anything to allow for image upload and it just hangs there. Same thing happens when I try to select an image in the Banner Manager.

I've tried with different browsers and from different locations...

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Have you been messing around with any core Joomla code? have you got any libraries other than mootools running in the backend?

Comment: Things were working fine for the past 5 months, we haven't change anything to the joomla core. No changes at all.

Comment: I searched around and suggested to disable flash uploader in the media manager which is disabled.